# 18x18 Board Array Index Out of Bounds

Tags: java, arrays, unix

```
// Counts the neighbors of alive or dead cells in boolean grid.
    public static int countNeighbors ( final boolean[][] grid, final int row, final int col ) {
        // Finds neighbors in top row.
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i > -1; --i) {
            if (grid[row - 1][col + i] == true) 
                count += 1;
            else if (grid[row - 1][col + i] == false)
                count += 0;
        }

        // Finds neighbors in same row.
        for (int i = 1; i > -1; --i) {
            if (grid[row][col + i] == true) 
                count += 1;
            else if (grid[row][col + i] == false)
                count += 0;
        }

        // Finds neighbors in bottom row.
        for (int i = 1; i > -1; --i) {
            if (grid[row + 1][col + i] == true)
                count += 1;
            else if (grid[row + 1][col + i] == false)
                count += 0;
        }

        return count;
    }
```

Getting an array out of bounds exception when I attempt to find all true neighbor values in all 8 blocks around the specified square.

I figured the code would already handle if it was out of bounds as I assume those values would be false anyways.

Comment: What's your question? Just check that row and col are within range before accessing the array.

Comment: This code is full of problems.  Just the first `if` statement (`if (grid[row - 1][col + i] == true)`) will result in an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Java arrays are zero-based.

Comment: Well the method is meant to take in a boolean-based 18x18 2D array with an approximate position, and check the three cells above of it for any true values, and adds to a counter. Same for the row the 2D array position is in, and the row below it. Im not sure how else I can move around the array position without going out of bounds.

Comment: Use another way check the cells, where the position parameters are equal to zero or (array length -1).

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate function to get the grid cell, including a bounds check:

```
public static boolean getGridCell ( final boolean[][] grid, final int row, final int col )
{
     // bounds check:
     if((row < 0) || (row >= grid.length))
         return false;
     if((col < 0) || (col >= grid[row].length))
         return false;

     return grid[row][col];
}
```

Then call this function instead of accessing the grid directly:

```
public static int countNeighbors ( final boolean[][] grid, final int row, final int col ) {
    // Finds neighbors in top row.
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i >= -1; --i) {
        if (getGridCell(grid, row - 1,col + i)) 
            count += 1;
    }

    // Finds neighbors in same row.
    for (int i = 1; i >= -1; --i) {
        if (getGridCell(grid, row, col + i)) 
            count += 1;
    }

    // Finds neighbors in bottom row.
    for (int i = 1; i >= -1; --i) {
        if (getGridCell(grid, row + 1, col + i))
            count += 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Also:

- There's no need to check if the grid cell is empty and add zero to count if it is, because that isn't going to make any difference to the count.
- You don't need to test if(some_boolean == true), you can just write if(some_boolean)
- Your loop termination condition should be >= -1 not > -1, if you intend include -1.